# Single logout NameID relaying to application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

While B2C doesn't appear to support single logout, it is a requirement by many government provided IdP's.

Would it be possible to workaround the shortcoming by

1. relaying the NameID of the saml:Assertion the IdP returns after successful authentication from B2C to the application so that <<< essential question
2. when logging out, application could construct the required SAML LogoutRequest using the NameID
3. sign out first from B2C e.g., via ./auth/logout
4. then send user to IdP's logout page that will eventually return user back to "you've logged out" page on the application?

Comment: Yes, that will work by passing the `socialIdpUserId` claim out to your Azure AD B2C application, as long as you don't mind "the leaky abstraction".

Comment: Looks like socialIdpUserId has nothing to do with the NameID coming in the SAML Assertion. We basically would need to get hold of the full SAML Assertion message coming into BC after successful authentication at IdP. NameID node is right under the root Assertion node.